# Database is slow and there are lot of sqldump files in log folder

Tags: sql-server

One of my production databases suddenly hangs and processing of data becomes very slow.
When I investigated more I find that there are some SQL dump files being generated continuously.
Due to these files, the disk size also increases rapidly.

When I restart the SQL server service, everything works fine and after some days it's the same problem.

I tried looking into theses SQL dump files, but it's not easy to read these files without any software.

1. I want to find the reason for this issue.
2. Is it some procedure or query which creates this issue.
3. Is it something with the SQL server setup which is wrong.
4. Or is it something with the indexes or caching in tempdb which creates this critical issue.

I can provide some of the SQL dump files if anyone can help with it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This is definitely not the forum for someone to parse your dump files for you. That's a call for MS support ticket, and you should *definitely* open one. Are your drives full? Especially the ones holding the tlog.

Comment: The SQL error log files themselves should tell you why a stack dump was generated -- look for the `ERRORLOG` files. These also grow significantly if many dumps happen, but they should be much smaller than the actual dump files. Also, every dump should be accompanied by a `.log` file of the same name (e.g. `SQLDump0002.log`) which captures the error log just before the dump was produced, and a `.txt` which should contain the command executed that caused the dump (if it was the direct result of a command).

Comment: depends on if you are auto backing up, and the process is not closing after the sql dump. Or if someone is practicing code injection.

Comment: check cron schedules as well as the triggers.

Comment: Avoid using php for mail as filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) causes 
 security issues because of a flaw that will cause a root shell command to be remotely executed.

Comment: strip EXIF headers on pictures to avoid php and javascript injection.

Comment: @drtechno: none of this has anything to do whatsoever with SQL Server producing error dumps, which are the result of the engine hitting an exception. You may be thinking of MySQL, which uses a "dump" command to produce backups. Calling a backup on SQL Server a "dump" would be very confusing.

Comment: is it an error dump, or a database backup made with a dump command?

Comment: or is it an exception error caused by code injection, an after effect from executing a c++ vulnerability that executes a shell command to run from the server (common web servers' vpn/internet connection hijacking)

Comment: @drtechno : it is an error dump.

Comment: @JacobH: no my drives are not full and I don't understand what drives has to do with SQL dump. I have tried opening the files and managed to extract some information. But the procedure it says throws error works fine if I restart the sql service.

Comment: As @JeroenMostert mentioned, a SQL dump is a result of an exception in the engine. I've seen SQL dumps because of full drives (thus SQL can't write any more data). That was just my first thought after reading your post. Check the logs and open a case with MS. You are most likely losing data in these dumps.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Thanks. I get the name of the procedure from the .txt file, but I don't understand why it works fine if I restart the SQL server service. This hanging and SQL dumping behavior is very random and can happen after a week or every 2 days or can work fine for a month.

Comment: It would be hard to impossible for anyone who isn't Microsoft Support to diagnose and solve this remotely for you. You may be hitting a resource leak of some sort, or else your hardware is actually flaky (e.g. hitting undiagnosed bad memory that's not in use until SQL Server has been running for a long while, or a CPU that wobbles under thermal load), or else you've got a tricky threading bug in the engine itself that only manifests rarely. Check hardware, install the latest service pack/cumulative update and open a ticket with MS.